# About ethereum transaction hash & ECDSA hash function

Tags: transactions

I have some questions.

First, I can find a transaction hash on the etherscan website.  https://etherscan.io/
I want to know the content about transaction hash, that is, transaction hash=hash(content).
what's content?

Second, I know in the ethereum must sign ECDSA to generate "r,s,v", but in the ECDSA algorithm has a function hash(e), what' the content about that "e"?

The transaction hash =? hash(e)

The difference between the transaction hash and hash(e).

Thank you very much!

Comment: not the complete answer but the content is a transaction(from, to, nonce, value, data) and some extra data. some links that could help you: https://www.codementor.io/@yosriady/signing-and-verifying-ethereum-signatures-vhe8ro3h6  and https://medium.com/finnovate-io/how-do-i-sign-transactions-with-web3-f90a853904a2